# Is it possible to use a CSV file to assign to frames poses from a pose library?

Tags: armature, bones, csv

Is it possible to use a CSV file to assign to frames poses from a pose library? For example: having a CSV file with the frame number where a musical note is played. The musical note been the pose required to play the note on a saxophone.

I have done it for a vibraphone, using the CSV file to drive a bone which in turn with a driver moved the stick to the correct place. But it looks to mechanical. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have code to import a lipsync file to NLA tracks, one for each phoneme and action strips, the actions named after the phoneme.  https://github.com/batFINGER/sound-bake-drivers/blob/master/sound_drivers/NLALipsync.py  It would be quite simple to alter it to musical notes, if an NLA solution appeals.

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSV like control file which starts with the frame number, an object variable (short cut and a list of assignments where Arm.L references a bone layer and things like KuenHalf or Tan are pose names

```
0 SET:A=r6839C
1 A:All=IRAS
10 A:Arm.L=KuenHalf,Arm.R=Tan
20 A:Arm.L=Fook,Arm.R=Bong
30 A:Arm.L=KuenHalf,Arm.R=Tan
40 A:Arm.L=Fook,Arm.R=Bong
50 A:Arm.L=KuenHalf,Arm.R=Tan
60 A:Arm.L=Fook,Arm.R=Bong
```

The source to create the animation from a control file is on [github](https://github.com/3dbug/blender/blob/master/anim_from_csv.py).

Note that this was designed for Makehuman created MHX rigs.

Comment: Hi Stacker, this looks great to me but I have discovered that I need to make some changes to my character armature before going futher.I have never done Python scripting but with my knowledge in Turbo Pascal and Visual Basic I should be able to manage. Thanks.